# Why does validation not work when exclusion :in points to a variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, validation

I have the following in my ActiveRecord validation:

```
validates :username, :exclusion => { :in => %w(admin admins administrator administrators), :message => "\"%{value}\" is reserved."}
```

which works as it should. But when I replace it with:

```
validates :username, :exclusion => { :in => @reserved_words, :message => "\"%{value}\" is reserved."}
@reserved_words = ["admin","admins","administrator","administrators"]
```

I get the following error:

> An object with the method #include? or a proc or lambda is required, and must be supplied as the :in option of the configuration hash.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you really initialize your `@reserved_words` variable AFTER it's been used? Your lines should be swapped!